# Treeview with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, treeview

I need create a treeview with angular. Right now i created something linke this;

```
<ol>
   <li ng-repeat="item in nodes.data" data-ng-click="getSub(item.id)">
      {{item.name}}
     <ul>
       <li>
         {{item.name}}
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ol>
```

So what i expected is that for first has a root item, when i click over it, i start a function to check subitems (the function is the same even to check the root item). But actually it's not working.
So what i need that when i click on

item starts the http call and as a treeview in that

load the correspondent item. Example of the structure;

Every click on item1 starts the call and load as a tree the next item1 (same fot item2)

```
item1
  item1
    item1
     item1

item2
  item2
```

is it possible?
This is a Plunker i made: http://plnkr.co/edit/hWLO5GQbVeJuY88KUy4t?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It's because getSub is set on external `<li>` that includes all nested `<li>`s.

You have to create a new dom element, for example  and attach to it the click function

```
<li ng-repeat="item in nodes.data">
  <span data-ng-click="getSub(item.id)">{{item.name}}</span>
```

Comment: Can you please try to modify the Plunker and show me?

Comment: The Plunker does not work (and I don't have rights to save...)

Comment: You can fork from that another one and you can save if you want

Comment: mmh...i don't understand exactly what you have done..i should be able to add another children in the tree when i click in the children of item1